# Cursor isn't Visible

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin, warp-terminal

I use neovim in my warp terminal and earlier my cursor was clearly visible. I did not change any settings and neither my background color was changed. How can I fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK8Ew.png)

Apparently the cursor is present in the above picture attached but it's hard to extremely hard to navigate.

I did try to fix the settings through plug-ins but i was unable to get the solution.